# Mongodb get two value from different collection and calculate percentage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in mongodb.

I want to try to calculate success rate. I need to divide sent.TOTAL / targetAudience  if sent.TOTAL / targetAudience lower than 0.9 return 0 else return 1. I share my script below. But it returns error: $divide only supports numeric types, not array and array

```
message:

                {
                        "_id" : 1727,
                        "appKey" : "morhipo",
                        "msgMethod" : "CAMPAIGN",
                        "allowApiOverride" : false,
                        "firstChildId" : 0,
                        "secondChildId" : 0,
                        "sampleRate" : 0,
                        "targetAudience" : 1135195
                }



       msgstats:
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b4ddd02f4eb8c72b57e89bb"),
                        "mid" : 1727,
                        "sent" : {
                                "TOTAL" : 756023,
                                "ANDROID" : 398973,
                                "IOS" : 357050
                        }

            // MY Script
            var condition =0;
            var bol =0;
            db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(dbName) {
            var instColl=db.getMongo().getDB(dbName).getCollection("message");
            var sending = instColl.aggregate([
              {
                $match: {
                 "endDate" : {$gt:new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-10)),$lte:new Date()},"sendStatus" : "FINISHED","msgMethod" : "CAMPAIGN"
                }
              },
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: "msgStats",
                  localField: "_id",
                  foreignField: "mid",
                  as: "docs"
                }
              },
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: "message",
                  localField: "_id",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "docs1"
                }
              },
              {
                "$project": {
                  "bol":{"$divide":["$docs.sent.TOTAL","$docs1.targetAudience"]},
                  "condition":{"$cond":{if:{$lt:["$bol",0.9]},then: 1, else:0}
                  }
                }
              }
            ]);
            print(condition);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) returns output as array. You have to use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to extract the single element from array.

Use below [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage. [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) expression to read the single element followed by calculation inside [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to output boolean value.

```
{
  "$project":{
    "condition":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{
          "total":{"$arrayElemAt":["$docs.sent.TOTAL",0]},
          "targetAudience":{"$arrayElemAt":["$docs1.targetAudience",0]}},
        "in":{
          "$cond":{
            "if":{"$lt":[{"$divide":["$$total","$$targetAudience"]},0.9]},
            "then":1,
            "else":0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your returns. But although it is numeric, it returns $arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array, but is string.

Comment: Sorry missed the $. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your docs and docs1 is an array so you can't directly access an array in arithmetic operations. So you need to unwind those arrays.

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

```
db.message.aggregate([
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "msgstats",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "mid",
              as: "docs"
            }
          },{
            $lookup: {
              from: "message",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "docs1"
            }
          },
          {"$unwind" : "$docs"},
          {"$unwind" : "$docs1"},
                        {
            "$project": {
              "bol":{"$divide":["$docs.sent.TOTAL","$docs1.targetAudience"]},
              "condition":{
                  "$cond":{
                      if:{
                          $lt:[{"$divide":["$docs.sent.TOTAL","$docs1.targetAudience"]},0.9]}
                          ,then: 1, 
                          else:0
                      }
              }
            }
          }
        ]);
```

Comment: it works fine. Thanks but if condititon doesnt work correctly. it should be return 0 if "$bol" lower than 0.9 but it returns always 1                                                                                                    "_id" : 1719, "bol" : 1.0000048867615188, "condition" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1721, "bol" : 0.9689045955061818, "condition" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1723, "bol" : 0.9999991188790732, "condition" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1725, "bol" : 0.8306092453226359, "condition" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1726, "bol" : 0.6664722162186975, "condition" : 1 }

Comment: You can use this ====>   {
                "$project": {
                  "bol":{"$divide":["$docs.sent.TOTAL","$docs1.targetAudience"]},
                  "condition":{
                      "$cond":{
                          if:{
                              $lt:[{"$divide":["$docs.sent.TOTAL","$docs1.targetAudience"]},0.9]}
                              ,then: 1, 
                              else:0
                          }
                  }
                }
              }